# Why is the integer named Fixnum in ruby?

Tags: ruby, history, naming

I was wondering why Ruby names it `Fixnum`; other languages name it Integer, Int, Number, etc. I saw that `Fixnum < Integer` and `Bignum < Integer`, and `Integer < Numeric` and `Float < Numeric`. I guess it's because of the size:

```
1.class => Fixnum
(10**100).class => Bignum
```

And from [the doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Fixnum.html):

> Holds Integer values that can be represented in a native machine word (minus 1 bit). If any operation on a Fixnum exceeds this range, the value is automatically converted to a Bignum

Why the name `Fixnum`? I thought about fixed number, but it's not fixed, nor fixed size number.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the reasoning behind the design of a language.

Comment: Which stack exchange should it be moved to?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This isn't something Ruby came up with — the term "fixnum" comes from Lisp. Just like in Ruby, a fixnum in Lisp is a number that can be represented by a machine integer. Although I've never seen a primary source to prove I'm right, I've always assumed the "fix" part of the name referred to the fact that it can only represent a fixed range of numbers, in contrast with the limitless bignum (which gets its freedom from limits at the expense of worse performance).

Comment: I believe that `Fix` actually refers to the fact that `Fixnum`s are immutable. There is only one instance of `Fixnum` for each integer value, therefore the reference is "fixed".

Comment: @Alex.Bullard: I don't believe bignums or any other kind of number are normally mutable either, though. Were bignums originally mutable or something?

Comment: @Alex.Bullard Whether or not a number is immutable is Ruby specific. If the word indeed came from Lisp, then that cannot be the reason for the terminology "fix".

Comment: @Chuck I may be wrong, but I think the term "fixed" is opposed to "float": whether or not the decimal point moves. The opposition between fixnum and bignum became after, I think.

Comment: Ah thanks, so now why lisp named it fixnum?

Comment: @sawa: I initially found that hard to swallow since fixnums are always integers and not fixed-point real numbers (which is usually what "fixed-point" means in my experience), but the Lisp 1.5 manual does seem to suggest that you're right, using "fixed-point" to describe what appear to be simple integers.

Answer (score 2):

Integer has 2 kinds of children:

Those that can be represented in a native machine word (minus 1 bit):
   Fixnums. (Check out the `object_id` of smallish integers. Notice a
   pattern? Try some other objects, strings, arrays, whatever. That's
   where the minus 1 bit comes from).

And those which are too large: Bignums (For these an object_id is just
   like other non-Fixnums.)

```
p 1.is_a?(Integer) #=> true
p (10**100).is_a?(Integer) #=> true
```

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby it's an object that has an immediate value. Which basically means that the object is passed rather than the value. So in all honesty it's just the name of the object not really the type.

Read more here: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Fixnum.html